# informacion sobre version de docker(17.06.0-dev)

Tags: docker

hace una semana descarge esta version de docker, la cuestion es que docker deberia funcionar solo con windows 10, sin embargo esta version en peculiar por dos cosas, lo puedo ejecutar desde un windows 7 y segundo porque no encuentro un parecido en google con una version '-dev'.¿Esta version me permite trabajar con docker normalmente?

Answer (score 0):

Si funciona en Windows 7 debes haber descargado Docker Toolbox ya que como dices Docker for Windows solo funciona en Windows 10 por el soporte Hyper-V que necesita.

Docker Toolbox lo puedes usar perfectamente en Windows 7 en su versión definitiva no tiene que ser Dev.

Ahora si lo que digo no es lo que estás usando por favor postea aquí como lo descargaste y como lo estás usando para ver.

Saludos